# I am building a flutter desktop application, and i want to have a color picker on form just like this one

Tags: flutter, colors, desktop

I tried using color picker package but it isn't what i am looking for

i want to have something like this

[image]

Comment: I think you use Overlay or PopUpmenu to show single Row with this color items

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.